# How to fix "type_info's has hidden visibility. They should all have public visibility."?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang++, appkit

On the macOS system console this error is logged when launching one of my apps:

> APP[28193]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   17CPPNameOfClassA, 28CPPNameOfClassB.

It does not impact functionality (yet) as far as I can tell but obviously something is wrong. Inspecting the source of this warning in the **Clang** sources also suggests that it has a performance impact.

This is generated for a framework including C++ classes used by other frameworks in my app referencing it.

FWIW, the warning is caused by the `private_typeinfo.cpp` class in **Clang** (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxxabi/blob/master/src/private_typeinfo.cpp).

According to the *Controlling Symbol Visibility* chapter in Apple's *C++ Runtime Environment Programming Guide* I should be able to control visibility on a class level with attributes or GCC pragmas.

Thing is the symbol is already visible as far as I can tell with `nm` and my frameworks all already have `Default` visibility (i.e. *NOT* `Hidden`).

Also using either (attribute or pragma) to force default visibility causes the app to crash where it only created the warning before.

Weirdly this warning is only generated for some classes while a majority of other classes **in the same compilation unit/framework** don't cause any warnings.

Any further hints or ideas on how to fix this issue greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had this error and it was caused by trying to dynamic_cast something that was an uninitialized variable, but happened to be holding a pointer to an object from a different class hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but maybe this will help someone else with the same problem.

One of the reasons this could happen is that your app loads several different versions of the same library. For example in my case, I simply didn't remove a path to old version from library search path. Try to see (in debugger) what libraries are loaded in your app, and check that the same library wasn't loaded from different locations.

While trying to resolve this, I found these links useful: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=42566, http://www.russellmcc.com/posts/2013-08-03-rtti.html.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm just using a bunch of my own frameworks in this app.

Comment: Great answer, author of that article really helped me with proposed unit test!
I am having similar issue while porting huge commercial product to MacOS, I believe this unit test will be useful.

Comment: @AlexanderBelyi, I copy everything into the Bundle. So while I have 2 copies of the libraries only one is loaded - from the Bundle. Also in my case I have this error running from the Xcode - when I run it from Terminal everything is good. Any idea how to trace it and fix it?

Comment: @AlexanderBelyi, I am being hit by the same issue. I'm using wxWIdgets and bunch of my own dylibs. I modified Xcode project manually by adding the result of `wx-config --libs` to the Linker options and then added script to copy all dylibs inside the Bundle. But running the program from inside the Xcode I see it loads from both inside the Bundle and from the place it links the libraries from. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Igor, Sorry, I haven't been using Xcode for a while now, so not sure.